# InfluxQL to Flux

Tags: influxdb, influxql

What is the equivalent of this query

```
select sum("count") from "measurement_name" where time<now() and time>now()-4d group by time(100s),"source"
```

in Flux? I have tried

```
from(bucket:"metrics/default_metrics") 
 |> range(start: -4d) 
 |> filter(fn: (r)=> r._measurement == "measurement_name")
 |> group(columns: ["source"]) 
 |> window(every: 100s) 
 |> drop(columns:["_start","_stop","_measurement","column_a","column_b"]) 
 |> yield()
```

and

```
from(bucket:"metrics/default_metrics") 
 |> range(start: -4d) 
 |> filter(fn: (r)=> r._measurement == "measurement_name") 
 |> window(every: 100s) 
 |> group(columns: ["source"])  
 |> drop(columns:["_start","_stop","_measurement","column_a","column_b"]) 
 |> yield()
```

but they all seem to yield different results

This is grouping by `time_interval = 100s` and `source`. Supposedly, the grouping by time (and the sum aggregation implicitly?) is done using the `window` function from Flux but the result from the InfluxQL query (select...) are:

```
name: measurement_name
tags: source=source_name
time                sum
----                ---
1601022500000000000 39
1601022600000000000 191
1601022700000000000 232
1601022800000000000 145
1601022900000000000 207
1601023000000000000 277
1601023100000000000 160
1601023200000000000 228
1601023300000000000 253
1601023400000000000 167
```

while the one coming from the Flux queries is

```
Table: keys: [source]
source:string        _time:time                                 _value:int    _field:string  
----------------------  ------------------------------  --------------------------  -------- 

source_name  2020-09-25T11:46:51.390000000Z                           6              count  
source_name  2020-09-25T11:46:54.124000000Z                           5              count  
source_name  2020-09-25T11:46:57.616000000Z                           6              count  
source_name  2020-09-25T11:46:57.999000000Z                           9              count  
source_name  2020-09-25T11:46:58.064000000Z                           3              count  
source_name  2020-09-25T11:46:58.307000000Z                           6              count  
source_name  2020-09-25T11:47:01.011000000Z                           8              count  
source_name  2020-09-25T11:47:03.634000000Z                           6              count  
source_name  2020-09-25T11:47:03.700000000Z                           8              count  
source_name  2020-09-25T11:47:04.144000000Z                           8              count
```

The end goal is to plot this out in Grafana.

Is there also maybe a way to convert back and forth between these two paradigms? Whenever it's possible ofcourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `sum()` function explicitly. I suggest using [`aggregateWindow()`](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/flux/guides/window-aggregate/#summing-up) too.

```
from(bucket:"metrics/default_metrics") 
 |> range(start: -4d) 
 |> filter(fn: (r)=> r._measurement == "measurement_name")
 |> group(columns: ["source"])
 |> aggregateWindow(every: 100s, fn: sum)
 |> drop(columns:["_start","_stop","_measurement","column_a","column_b"]) 
 |> yield()
```

Generally, `group` does not preserve sort order but `aggregateWindow` sorts by time before doing its work. That's something to look for. Additionally, the time bounds might not line up exactly between the Flux and InfluxQL queries. I expect them to, but double check it.